# Sort geometry + data table in ArcGIS with Permanently Sort Records (PSR) v1.0

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, fields-attributes, sorting, error-000576

When i run Sort geometry + data table in ArcGIS with Permanently Sort Records (PSR) v1.0 the algorithm gives an error:

```
Order_ ASCENDING # # # #
Start Time: Fri Mar 01 17:06:33 2013
000576 ERROR: Script Associated with this tool does not exist.
Failed to execute (sortrecords).
End Time: Fri Mar 01 17:06:33 2013 (Elapsed Time: 0.00 seconds)
```

Do you know why?

Comment: If this is Chris Snyder's python-based script/toolbox, someone on the ArcGIS forums said that he had to update the script location in the properties. Sorry, I don't know much about gp or python to be of more help.

Comment: ArcGIS 10.1 has a new Sort tool that permanently sorts the table and/or Geometry.

Comment: Hi, mkennedy, that' it.
It's solved. It was the path to the python file.
Thank you,
Valter.

Comment: At some stage @mkennedy (who I thank for kind words during recent moderator election) might like to transfer her Comment to an Answer that you can then Accept.

Answer (score 2):

If this is Chris Snyder's python-based script/toolbox, someone on the ArcGIS forums said that he had to update the script location in the properties.

I don't know much about gp or python to be of more help.